# Read and edit the DOM of an HTML file in Node

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, dom, jsdom

In a node script, I want to crawl through a HTML file, maybe edit the content of certain tags, and save it to the file.

I was able to crawl and edit the tags using jquery and jsdom, but I have to figure out how to save something to the file after making those changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use fs module. -> [API DOC](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

example:

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("./path/to/file.txt");

stream.once('open', function() {
    stream.write('something');
    stream.end();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, the fs module is really good for saving the data back to a file! But if I just pull the dom from jquery through $("html").html(), will it preserve formatting? Also, if it has non-html thing, like django templating commands, will it crash?